# Prevent duplicate form submission while maintaining viewstate in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, postback, post-redirect-get

I have a form that people can use to upload files, and I want to make sure that pressing the refresh button after an upload does not trigger a duplicate upload. The methods I'm considering are session variables and page redirection (post/redirect/get pattern), but they both have problems

**session variables**

Problem is they're shared between pages, so refreshes may be incorrectly detected if the user has multiple pages open employing the same logic, or if they have multiple copies of the same page open on different records. The other problem is session state expires, so it's not quite reliable. However I'll post the code in case it's helpful to someone. This function should be called in the page on_load event and it's return value assigned to a variable which is checked in the submit events of your forms.

```
Private Function checkForRefreshOnLoadAfterPostback() As Boolean
    Dim refreshed As Boolean = (Page.IsPostBack AndAlso Session("GuidOnloadPostbackRefreshCheck") <> ViewState("GuidOnloadPostbackRefreshCheck"))
    Session("GuidOnloadPostbackRefreshCheck") = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    ViewState("GuidOnloadPostbackRefreshCheck") = Session("GuidOnloadPostbackRefreshCheck")
    Return refreshed
End Function
```

**Post/Redirect/Get**

Option 2 is to redirect the page after the form submission is processed, however my page has tabs with other form controls that I'd like to preserve the values of if possible. So my question is, how can I maintain the viewState of the page while preventing the form being submitted a second time after a refresh? Is there some way to selectively remove data from the page headers?